# Is passing WinForm Controls between Classes dangerous/inefficient?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

Since almost all projects I create contains ListViews I got the idea to do a Class which contains all the important functions to modify the ListView. It would look something like this:

MainForm:

```
ListViewFunctions LVF = new ListViewFunctions();
ListView newLV = new ListView();
newLV = LVF.AddItem(newLV, new List<string> { "item", "subitem1", "subitem2" });
```

Class:

```
Public class ListViewFunctions
{
   public ListView AddItem(ListView LV, List<string> InputStrings)
   {
       if (InputStrings.Count > 0)
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < InputStrings.Count; i++)
           {
               if (i == 0)
                   LV.Items.Add(InputStrings[0]);
               else
                   LV.Items[LV.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(InputStrings[i]);
           }
       }
       return LV;
    }
}
```

However I'm not sure if passing controls to a class like above is considered dangerous nor how it would affect the performance. So I'm hoping that someone can answer if it is safe or not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not entirely dangerous just indicates a bad design flow. Nothing wrong with just storing the list of items to go into each list view somewhere

Comment: Why not just extend `ListView`?

Comment: If you're doing this, you could probably use extension methods as well. Or as bmused said, extend `ListView`.

Comment: @bmused Do you want to point me towards an example of how to do this?

Comment: I misunderstood your question, @bmused is correct, you could create an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)

Comment: Thank you guys, I see now that extending the ListView is the most valid solution.

Comment: Short from creating components with UserControls and derived classes, one implementation detail for the Form class is often overlooked.  It is a *partial* class.  You can create any number of parts.  Which simply lets you move code into another source code file to logically organize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably only use a helper class as you have done if I was planning to make it generic so I could utilise the class on other types.

Creating a custom control by extending `ListView` may be a preferable way to implement your extra `ListView` methods.

```
public class MyCustomListView : ListView
{

//...

}
```

Comment: +1 - Although I think an extension method would be easier for OP to implement to an existing project

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are concerned, if it's *not* manipulated bye different threads at the same time which may lead to synchronization problem leading also to scrammbled or unstable object state, it's completely valid to pass class reference to other class
from a software engineering point of view, it affect maintainability and bug tracking, as suggested, try extending the ListView class like so:

```
public static HelperClass
{
  public static void AddItems(this ListView, params string[] itemsToAdd)
  {
     // to-do
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes sharing a user control makes a lot of sense. However, most of the time, that's not the case.  When this technique is useful, it's extremely useful. However, use it only when it's necessary because most of the time it makes your applications unnecessarily complex